# How to integrate JNI shared library in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, java-native-interface, tomcat8, gdal

I tried searching on the web but I could not find any relevant tutorial or how-to for integrating JNI shared libraries into Spring Boot project. I would like to integrate GDAL library with a small Spring Boot REST application.

Is it even possible to use JNI with embedded Tomcat?

Can someone provide links or an explanation on how to include compiled jar and actual library files into a Spring Boot project?
Maven would be a prefered build option, but gradle would work too.

Comment: Hello, I would like to know if you have found a solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Yes, I actually found an alternative solution, but since I changed the place of employment, I no longer have access to this code and I can't remember the details.
What I do remember is that I used a Docker container for the containment of the GDAL libs and Spring Boot application but I don't remember the details of the Spring Boot configuration used. :(
Sorry.

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway :)

Comment: Maybe this is something one might find interesting: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo031

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing exactly the same situation.
My app has an embedded JNI library that i cannot to embedd at WAR file.
To run from Eclipse, it executes normally but for WAR file build it's not possible.
I believe that the solution key is about the repackage goal of 'spring-boot-maven-plugin' but I got few information about that.
Regards,

Comment: Please, share if you find out anything. I was able to run the SB app with executable war and JNI jar included in the project as in maven local repository.
I think that embedded Tomcat ignores a shared folder property but since SB embedded Tomcat usually runs only one web app it's not an issue.
But it does complicate my deployment procedure since I have to extract a gdal.jar file that is built inside a Docker container (in which I actually run the app in the end).